# How to change UIButton backgroundimage when tag value is known?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uiimage

How I can change a`UIButton` background image if I know the tag value for that`UIButton` ?

Suppose I have a`UIButton` created programmatically and I set the tag to 5

now I want change background image of that`UIButton` on event where I only know the tag value of that button.

Comment: First check if button.tag==5 if you then write this line...  [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"me.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try with this.

```
UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:5];
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"me.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Only use this when you want a cricket player as your `UIButton` image